# How to remove text that get stuck after closing or switching from browser

Tags: windows-10, browser

I face this issue many time, whenever I switch from a browser to any other application or browser or anything else. The browser text gets stuck and it doesn't go away until I go back to that page of the browser or restart my system.

[image]

Can any one tell me how to get rid of it as it's sometimes difficult to find the browser tab form where the text is appearing.

Comment: Is it only happening with a particular browser, or with any?

Comment: I use mostly chrome, but it's not specific to that browser

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is not specific to a browser to most likely culprit is not the browser, but the video-driver.

Get the latest drivers for your video-card and install those. Most likely that will fix this problem.

Please note: Get the drivers directly from the manufacturer of the video-card (e.g Nvidia, AMD or Intel). The drivers supplied by your computer-vendor are most likely NOT the latest drivers.